# How to delete data from table cache using data factory?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory

I have a data factory pipeline that is taking data from SQL Server and copying it to table storage:

```
Azure Sql Server View --> Table Storage Cache
```

This step is doing a `REPLACE` of the specific row based on a `guid` from the SQL Server view.

If a record is deleted from the source view, how do we delete that same record from table storage?

Comment: if you can add the corresponding JSON for this pipeline with the copy activity and reproduce the problem from our end  would be very helpful

Comment: @SaulCruz there's no problem. i'd like to know if there is an activity that will flush/fill or just delete records from table storage

Answer (score 0):

During the Copy Active, we couldn't do operation to the table data. Data Factory does not support this operation.

I have created a data pipeline to copy data from my SQL Server to the table storage for the test. Before your Copy Active begin, you can delete or insert your record as you want. And you can preview the data in Data Factory. Once the Copy Active is published and finished, it means that your data have been copied to the table storage.

If your really need to delete the same record in Table Storage, one of the ways is that you can login you Azure portal and using the "Storage Explorer(preview)" to delete the record:
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think the question is more about automating the DELETE process based on the source data, like a SQL MERGE WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE based on a row guid. I however +1 for the additional info on how you can manually modify the data.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a hint -- some code I have run in production for years... the idea is to have the source use a timestamp (or simpler flag) on deleted records and then to have your MERGE respect it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [DataFactory].[MergeCompany]
(
  @Company [DataFactory].[CompanyType] READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN

  MERGE INTO [Company] AS TGT
  USING @Company As SRC
  ON TGT.pk = SRC.pk
  --
  WHEN MATCHED AND SRC.aud_delete_date IS NOT NULL
  THEN DELETE
  --
  WHEN MATCHED AND SRC.aud_delete_date IS NULL
  THEN UPDATE SET
     TGT.comp_number     = SRC.comp_number                           
    ,TGT.comp_name       = SRC.comp_name                                
    ,TGT.aud_update_date = SRC.aud_update_date    
    ,TGT.aud_create_date = SRC.aud_create_date                            
  --
  WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
  THEN INSERT(
     pk
    ,comp_number    
    ,comp_name      
    ,aud_update_date
    ,aud_create_date                            
  ) 
  VALUES(
     SRC.pk
    ,SRC.comp_number    
    ,SRC.comp_name      
    ,SRC.aud_update_date
    ,SRC.aud_create_date                            
  )
  ; -- Required semicolon

END
GO
```

Comment: What does this have to do with data factory?